# Bootstrap5 Mobile Friendly Web

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, mobile-website

I am working on a web app and need it to be compatible with mobile devices.

The web app is written using Django, I am using Bootstrap 5 for arranging the page to be responsive. I am totally a newbie with mobile frontend development.

Now I understand that the grid system could help us scale the whole page to fit mobile devices properly. But as the page is developed using desktop, when viewing in mobile devices, the elements in the page is so small. I was originally thinking that Bootstrap would magically enlarge each row when it scale to fit mobile devices, but that's not the case.

Consulting with my friends, we seem to need to manually set size (width * height) based on the device-width. Then that's a lot of work. Is this the only way to go?

The page does scale to fit mobile devices, but each card is so small that it is very difficult to see the text/button.

```html
<head>
  <title>.....</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="container-lg pt-1">
  <div class="Heading .text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-sm-12">Title Here</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target=".navbar" data-bs-offset="50">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center sticky-top">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        {% for categ in categories_list %}
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#{{categ.split|join:'-'}}"> {{categ}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </nav>

    {% for categ in categories_list %} {% with entrees=foods_by_categ|get_item:categ %}
    <div id="{{categ.split|join:'-'}}">
      <h3>{{categ|capfirst}}</h3>
      {% for entree in entrees %}
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          {{entree.name}}
          <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#food-{{entree.id}}" class="btn float-end">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
        {% if entree.description %}

        <div class="card-body">
          <pre>{{entree.description}}</pre>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <form id="food-{{entree.id}}" action="{% url 'cart:add2cart' %}" class="card-body modal fade" method="post">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              {% with add2cart_form=add2cart_forms|get_item:entree.name %} {% csrf_token %} {{ add2cart_form.non_field_errors }}

              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{entree.name}}</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                  {% if entree.small_available %}
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{ add2cart_form.size_opt.errors }} {{ add2cart_form.size_opt.label_tag}} {{ add2cart_form.size_opt }}
                  </li>
                  {% endif %}



                  <li class="list-group-item">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Add</button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              {% endwith %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endwith %} {% endfor %}

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example HTML/CSS code you use for the app?

Comment: An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be better when sharing the code. Re: Bootstrap 5, as you know the grid system, please take a look at [Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/) They are the building blocks of responsive design.  CSS Media queries are being used there. If you don't know about media queries, read [a complete guide to css media queries](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)

Comment: Seems you forgot to add container/row/column classes for the cards. Check out the documentation for "Grid Cards" and add the classes you want. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#grid-cards

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: A proper demo would contain rendered HTML, not server-side code. Please replace that so we can see the problem.